# Missing og meta tags when running debug

Tags: video, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I am adding the proper meta tages to my video sharing website but Facebook continues to say they are not found. However, when I view source I see them. Can you please look at my source and tell me what I am doing wrong?

http://www.christianclips.com/video/151/Cannon-Ball-Baptism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago on a server running an old version of php (5.2.x)

The same pages would be parsed flawlessly on other servers yet they failed on this one.

I compared the headers and voilá, "Content-length" wasn't there. After adding it, everything started to work.

These are the headers for your page:

Date    Wed, 31 Aug 2011 17:08:45 GMT

Server  Apache

X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17

Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Pragma  no-cache

Content-Encoding    gzip

Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100

Connection  Keep-Alive

Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Content-Type    text/html

Content-Length is missing.

Facebook will not parse it until it finds the Content-Length header with a proper value.

I hope this helps

cheers

kal

Comment: That was it!!! Just commented our GZip in the php file and Content-length appeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's because you are missing a doctype. There are also other [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.christianclips.com/video/151/Cannon-Ball-Baptism&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) with the page that may be causing it to not find them properly.

Comment: That wasn't it, I just added the basic doctype <!DOCTYPE html> and still no luck on the debug page.

Comment: I also used my original doctype and still no luck <!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Switch it back to the xhtml doctype you originally had and then debug the url with Facebook linter tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: So i added the original doctype back and still no luck    http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.christianclips.com%2Fvideo%2F151%2FCannon-Ball-Baptism

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with Facebook OpenGraph meta tags, the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (previously known as the Facebook Linter) is often very helpful — it will force a re-parse of your URL and show you what the OpenGraph parser can see about it.

It has the added benefit of updating Facebook's cached OG metadata for your URL, which is very useful when you've newly updated that content.