# Facebook Connect Debugger and site won't use Meta Tags

Tags: drupal, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm trying to use Facebook Comments on a Drupal website correctly.  The comment box shows up and works exactly as I want it to, but when I go to facebook debugger http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it tells me that none of the required open graph meta tags (og:title, etc.) are set.  It's not recognizing any of the meta tags, which also means I can't use the fb:admins tag to moderate comments.

My problem sounds very similar to this one:  [Missing og meta tags when running debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210634/missing-og-meta-tags-when-running-debug) but I manually set the Content-Length parameter using PHP and the meta Tags still are not being recognized by facebook.  I'm running PHP 5.2.9, and I have NO access to upgrading or editing it at all.  (University environment, they're a trifle slow and obfuscating when asking for server changes.)  I've found multiple questions on Stack Overflow along similar lines, and have tried implementing all the suggested fixes to no avail, any help would be appreciated!

Please let me know if I left out any needed info!  I'm getting quite frustrated here, it took about 3 minutes flat to get the facebook comments to work, and now hours and hours of work still haven't resolved this issue. . .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" 
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{my app id}" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{my facebook id}"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="sports_team" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/logo-200.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
```

Comment: Can you post the actual URL for this? I'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Putting those meta tags on my page worked so I think you have the tags correct.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpaulisageek.com%2Ftmp%2Fso_7517794.php

Maybe you are issuing content before the `<head>`? Or your webserver isn't responding well to an HTTP query with a `Range:` header? Check your access logs for the exact query Facebook is making to see what to test.